# Log4j define multiple loggers

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I'm writing a REST service in Java ( with JAX-RS standard on Tomcat 9 ) and I want to add logs to my program for tracing his work when is called.

So I'm using Log4j (version 1.2.17) for writing my logs, and I want to write a different log file for each of my services running on my REST Service but I need to use only one log4j properties for the entire application

So I want this kind of logs in my log folder

```
--------------------------------
| Method | Log File            |
|------------------------------|
| /A     | MyRestService_A.log |
| /B     | MyRestService_B.log | 
--------------------------------
```

So I write this as configuration of Log4j ( **restServiceLogger.properties** ):

```
log4j.rootLogger=A,B

#/A
log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A.File=logs/MyRestService_A.log
log4j.appender.A.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.A.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n

#/B
log4j.appender.B=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.B.File=logs/MyRestService_B.log
log4j.appender.B.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.B.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.B.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.B.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
```

Then in the **/A** method I initialize the logger with this:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/restServiceLogger.properties");
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("A");
```

Then in the **/B** method I initialize the logger with this:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/restServiceLogger.properties");
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("B");
```

The problem is that when i write my logs they are all written in the /A log file (**MyRestService_A.log**).

How can I fix this by using only one properties for the entire project?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define logger in your configuration file each and use the same to get the `Logger` instance in you class file

e.g.

```
log4j.logger.A=,A    
log4j.additivity.A=false
```

and your class file, get the logger by name

e.g. in class A

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("A");`
```

Your log4j.properties files should be like below.

```
log4j.rootLogger=A,B

#/A
log4j.logger.A=,A
log4j.additivity.A=false
log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A.File=logs/MyRestService_A.log
log4j.appender.A.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.A.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n

#/B
log4j.logger.B=,B
log4j.additivity.B=false
log4j.appender.B=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.B.File=logs/MyRestService_B.log
log4j.appender.B.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.B.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.B.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.B.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
```